# difference between dma_alloc_coherent and kalloc+dma_map_single

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

In a system with IOMMU enabled, what is the difference between
-dma_alloc_coherent 
or
kalloc followed by dma_map_single.

I am confused in this

Answer (score 4):

`dma_alloc_coherent()` works pretty well if your kernel program just need to allocate a DMA buffer and keep using it until the program exits. It ensures coherency by flushing cache before CPU (your program) or DMA controller read from the DMA buffer  so you don't have to pay much attention to 'sync' CPU/cache/DMA controller before read/write to the DMA buffer. The only thing annoys me is that you need to keep track of the physical address dma_addr_t, buffer address and allocated size so you can `dma_free_coherent()` it properly later.

`dma_map_single()/dma_unmap_single()` are stream APIs and are supposed to have better performance than `dma_alloc_coherent()` in case the DMA buffer is single use for each call to DMA controller. Although I haven't seen any significant performance difference between them. And you are supposed to use `dma_sync_single_for_device()/dma_sync_single_for_cpu()` to assure coherency by yourself.

In some cases `dma_map_single()` is preferred over `dma_alloc_coherent()`. In one of my projects the DMA function has to take an allocated buffer (allocated by `kzalloc()/kmalloc()`) as parameter from the caller and map it to a DMA region. In this case I didn't have control over how and when the buffer would be allocated/free but can only map it to DMA region using `dma_map_single()/dma_unmap_single()`.

Comment: If you reuse buffer there is no need to map-unmap it often, sync API is for that purpose.